# My BOOTCAMP partition does not show up into finder, but I can boot into it

Tags: finder, bootcamp, windows, startup

I just uninstalled Windows 10 1903 using Bootcamp Assistant and upgraded to macOS 10.14.6 from an earlier version of macOS Mojave. After the system update, I downloaded the Windows 10 1903 iso from the official Microsoft website, installed Windows 10 1903 and the Bootcamp Drivers, then booted back into macOS. When I opened Finder, I noticed the BOOTCAMP drive was gone. In Disk Utility, it was unmounted and I couldn't mount it. I took a look at [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/244582/347690), in which it said that Windows was in a Hibernate state. It said that:

> Not really sure why Windows would ever be hibernate mode when shut down though, but a "power cycle" seemed to get it out of this mode and into a fully shut down state.

I tried booting up into Windows 10, then click shutdown, then turned on my Mac, booted into macOS, and the BOOTCAMP partition was still not there. What else should I try?

Pictures:
[image: Finder]
[image: Disk Utility]

Comment: Did you try disabling hibernation and fast start-up in Windows?  You can run `powercfg -h off`from elevated command prompt in Windows to do this.  See this [tenforums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-enable-disable-hibernate-windows-10-a.html#option1) tutorial.

Comment: Yes, disabling hibernation still does not fix the problem. The BOOTCAMP partition is still missing.

Comment: I took a look at this guy and he was having the same problem. [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250635848?page=1) I think it had something to do with the Mft record size being smaller than the sector size.